# Network IPv6 directly addressing a local server from the Internet

Tags: ipv6

The ISP was running out of IPv4 addresses so he 
gave us an IPv6; Now I have a static IPv6 address, which is good. 
According to the IPv6 description I should now be able to directly 
address any  device in the LAN from the WAN without going through 
Port forwarding to LAN IPv4 addresses (just setting the IPv6 Address 
and the Firewall permits).

Now when I ask for my IP address on any of the PC in the LAN
I get following 0000:aaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd:eeee:ffff:gggg 
The first 4 groups are always the same on any of the PCs, so that is my 
external public IP and the last 4 groups change not only by device
but also by time if called from the same PC (so that is this Interface
Identification created by the Program).
Now where is the IPv6  address part for an individual device in the LAN?
How can I get the IPv6 address of a device in the LAN and then address
that device directly from the WAN with that IPv6 address.  I can still
use my LAN server by using Port forwarding as I did before but how to 
change to this advanced direct IPv6 addressing?
Do I understand here something totally wrong ???

Comment: IPv6 just allows more addresses. That does not in any way increase security. Connect from the internet to your server directly would be very insecure and IPv6 does not change this

Comment: You can pretend you got public IPv4 addresses, that you distribute in your LAN with DHCP. That will answer many of your questions. Thinks do not change that much.

Answer (score 1):

> The first 4 groups are always the same on any of the PCs, so that is my external public IP

No – the first four groups are your LAN's *network prefix*. The actual IP address is all 8 groups, i.e. network prefix + interface identifier combined.

So the important difference is that your ISP doesn't merely assign you a single address in IPv6 – they assign you a whole network (i.e. address range).

(For comparison, in IPv4, if you had the typical /24-sized LAN network, then "192.168.1" would be the network prefix but "192.168.1.25" would be the whole IP address.)

> where is the IPv6 address part for an individual device in the LAN?

You're looking at it. `0000:aaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd:eeee:ffff:gggg` is the device's IP address.

> the last 4 groups change not only by device but also by time if called from the same PC

Whether the interface identifier changes over time or not is entirely up to the computer itself. (Most operating systems use the "privacy extensions" feature, which means they self-assign multiple addresses – the first one is static, the other ones change over time.)

So if you want a stable address for connecting *to* the computer, look at its own IP address list instead of asking a website – e.g. run `ip addr` on Linux or `ipconfig /all` on Windows, and pick the one which *doesn't* say "Temporary" next to it.

Answer (score 0):

IPv6 precludes
[NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation),
so no address translation is required. It is now replaced by firewall filters and
rules.

Because devices may be directly accessed/attacked from the internet,
firewall permitting, a random address is appended to the global prefix for the
purpose of obfuscating addresses, as
defined in the [DHCPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DHCPv6) standard.
As the number of possible values is enormous, an attacker is highly unlikely
to hit on an IPv6 address that is assigned to an actual device.

You may assign any device on the local network a static/non-random IPv6 address,
then define rules in the router's firewall for which access is allowed to that
address. This heavily depends on the quality of IPv6 support in the
router's firmware.

This practice is extremely risky, as by accessing the internet from this device
you could be disclosing its IPv6 address to an attacker.

You would be better off not using static IPv6 addresses, but using instead
a dynamic DNS service that supports IPv6 and dynamic detection or other
mechanisms. See for example the
[No-IP IP Detection Service](https://www.noip.com/integrate/ip-detection)
(no recommendation intended).
This option again depends on the capabilities of the firewall in your
router's firmware.